# Ubuntu 18.04 - move a window left-right in the same workspace

Tags: 18.04, shortcut-keys, gnome-shell

How to move half left - half right a window in the same workspace with shortcut on Ubuntu 18.04.

On 16.04 it was ctrl+win+ left or right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>Left Arrow</kbd>
<kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>Right Arrow</kbd>
<kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>Up Arrow</kbd>
<kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>Down Arrow</kbd>

Will snap to the half left, half right, full screen and the initially opened window position.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Oddly enough, my keys didn't work the way @YuganTej described above; after my upgrade from 16.04 LTS to 18.04 LTS. However, that answer did help me figure out how to move the windows to both sides of the screen, finally.

**The key combinations that work for me are:**

<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Left Arrow</kbd>

<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Right Arrow</kbd>

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Up Arrow</kbd>

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Down Arrow</kbd>

I also checked to see if anything from GNOME Extensions were conflicting, by toggling the ones I have installed (Workspace Matrix being one of them), but no cigar.