# Ubuntu 18.04 - move QT5 application to left or right

Tags: 18.04, .desktop, qt5, qgis

Most of the applications I use in Ubuntu 18.04 respond to <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> or <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>Right Arrow</kbd> to place the window on the left or right side, as explained in [Ubuntu 18.04 - move a window left-right in the same workspace](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1091975/ubuntu-18-04-move-a-window-left-right-in-the-same-workspace/1091997#1091997)

But I have one application I love, QGIS, made with QT5 that does not respond to these events.

I'm able to maximize or restore the size of QGIS with <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>Up Arrow</kbd> and <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>Down Arrow</kbd>, but not place it on the left or right.

Since it is a QT5 open source application, what can I do to make it able to move to the left or right with those standard keybindings?

Do I just need to change something in the `*.desktop` archive or do I have to change something in the application properties or build script?

Comment: I have *featherpad* and *qterminal*, both qt5 apps, and they obey Super+Left and Super+Right as you describe. So I'm guessing it's something specific to *QGIS*. Do you have these qt5 apps or any other qt5 app on your system to check?

Comment: Good point @dk-bose. In fact, I have `QT Creator` installed and it works file with Super+left and Super+right. It is built upon QT 5.x, the same as QGIS. I've checked both .desktop files and they look like the same. **It is something specific to the QGIS application**.